# lookup codes in data warehouse dimension

Tags: data-modeling, lookup, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

Many core entities in the upstream OLTP system have a **lot** of domain specific lookup codes that users are familiar with and wish to keep using in data warehouse reports. Things like product_category = "SRB6", incentive_scheme = "APP3" etc. These codes do have long form descriptions but that is not what users are familiar with nor want.

There is low correlation between the codes and cardinality is generally not that low, so a junk dimension doesn't seem right. The core dimensions are generally SCD type II and the lookup codes are unlikely to change.

How can I best model these lookup codes without using a snowflake of 3NF lookup tables around the dimension?

Options I can see include:

- place the code and long form description straight in the dimension table
- place the source system, code and description in a single global "lookups" dimension with a surrogate key and use that surrogate key in the entity dimension
- Combination of both; lookups dim surrogate key, code and description in the dimension and SCD type II the lookups dim
- Other ?

Answer (score 3):

The typical dimensional modelling approach is just to place the codes and long form descriptions straight in the dimension table they relate to. E.g. DimProduct would have columns describing the product category, both codes and descriptions if needed.

Other systems do prioritise generic management of lookups, normalisation, etc and would use other options as you've suggested, but they wouldn't be a dimensional model or benefit from the easy readability of the model and performance from reduced numbers of joins.

Comment: yes, I think it's the lookup management aspect that is clouding this one.

Comment: Ah, yes, you mentioned in the question that there are lots. The Kimball Group would have said that understandability of the model to users who don't understand databases, and performance should be your main goals: and if that means you have to do more work 'in the kitchen' behind the scenes to make things easier for the users, then so be it.